# Shooting technique

Tags: numerical-value, boundary-conditions

Here is my code, I am trying to plot the graph of the differential equation, But output graph is an empty window. can anyone please help in getting the graphs. This equation is a modified bessel equation of first and second kind.

Constants

```
k = 1.5;
H = 2;
\[Rho] = 1;
\[Mu] = 1;
\[EmptyUpTriangle] = (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]*H;
\[Alpha] = 2;
n = \[Alpha]^2 + \[EmptyUpTriangle]^2;
q = \[EmptyUpTriangle]*Sqrt[\[Mu]/\[Rho]];
p = Sqrt[q^2 + \[Alpha]^2];
\[Epsilon] = 0.1;
c = 0;
z = 0.5*\[Pi];
t = 1;
\[Sigma] = 0.01;
```

Differential equation with boundary conditions

```
n1 = NDSolve[{((y + k)^2*u100''[y]) + ((y + k)*u100'[y]) - u100[y] + 
      k*(y + k)*H^2 == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*u200''[y]) + ((y + k)*u200'[y]) - u200[y] + 
      k*(y + k)*\[Mu]*H^2 == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*f1''[y]) + ((y + k)*
        f1'[y]) - ((\[Alpha]*(y + k))^2 + 1)*f1[y] == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*f2''[y]) + ((y + k)*
        f2'[y]) - ((\[Alpha]*(y + k))^2 + 1)*f2[y] == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*f3''[y]) + ((y + k)*
        f3'[y]) - ((\[Alpha]*(y + k))^2 + 1)*f3[y] == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*f4''[y]) + ((y + k)*
        f4'[y]) - ((\[Alpha]*(y + k))^2 + 1)*f4[y] == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*u110''[y]) + ((y + k)*
        u110'[y]) - ((\[EmptyUpTriangle]*(y + k))^2 + 1)*u110[y] + 
      k*(y + k)*H^2 == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*u210''[y]) + ((y + k)*u210'[y]) - ((q*(y + k))^2 + 1)*
       u210[y] + k*\[Mu]*(y + k)*H^2 == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*f5''[y]) + ((y + k)*f5'[y]) - ((n*(y + k))^2 + 1)*
       f5[y] == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*f6''[y]) + ((y + k)*f6'[y]) - ((n*(y + k))^2 + 1)*
       f6[y] == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*f7''[y]) + ((y + k)*f7'[y]) - ((p*(y + k))^2 + 1)*
       f7[y] == 0,
    ((y + k)^2*f8''[y]) + ((y + k)*f8'[y]) - ((p*(y + k))^2 + 1)*
       f8[y] == 0,
    u100[-1] == 0, u200[1] == 0, 
    u100[0] == u200[0], \[Mu]*u100'[0] == u200'[0], 
    f1[-1] == -Cos[c]*u100'[-1], f2[-1] == -Sin[c]*u100'[-1], 
    f3[1] == -u200'[1], f4[1] == 0, f1[0] == f3[0], 
    f2[0] == f4[0], \[Mu]*f1'[0] == f3'[0], \[Mu]*f2'[0] == f4'[0], 
    u110[-1] == 0, u210[1] == 0, 
    u110[0] == u210[0], \[Mu]*u110[0] == u210[0], 
    f5[-1] == -Cos[c]*u110'[-1], f6[-1] == -Sin[c]*u110'[-1], 
    f7[1] == -u210'[1], f8[1] == 0, f5[0] == f7[0], 
    f6[0] == f8[0], \[Mu]*f5'[0] == f7'[0], \[Mu]*f6'[0] == 
     f8'[0]}, {u100, u200, u110, u210, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, 
    f8}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}}];
```

Expression for the velocity

```
u101 = Evaluate[{(f1[y]*Sin[\[Alpha]*z] + f2[y]*Cos[\[Alpha]*z]) /. 
         n1}];
    u201 = Evaluate[{(f3[y]*Sin[\[Alpha]*z] + f4[y]*Cos[\[Alpha]*z]) /. 
         n1}];
    u111 = Evaluate[{(f5[y]*Sin[\[Alpha]*z] + f6[y]*Cos[\[Alpha]*z]) /. 
         n1}];
    u211 = Evaluate[{(f7[y]*Sin[\[Alpha]*z] + f8[y]*Cos[\[Alpha]*z]) /. 
         n1}];
    u10 = Evaluate[{(u100 + \[Epsilon]*u101) /. n1}];
    u11 = Evaluate[{(u110 + \[Epsilon]*u111) /. n1}];
    u20 = Evaluate[{(u200 + \[Epsilon]*u201) /. n1}];
    u21 = Evaluate[{(u210 + \[Epsilon]*u211) /. n1}];
```

Plotting command

```
p1 = Plot[
      Piecewise[{{Re[
          Evaluate[(u10[y] + (\[Sigma]*(E^(I*t))*u11[y])) /. n1]], -1 <= 
          y <= 0}, {Re[
          Evaluate[(u20[y] + (\[Sigma]*(E^(I*t))*u21[y])) /. n1]], 
         0 <= y <= 1}}], {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, 
      AxesLabel -> {y, U}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Thick}, ImageSize -> 260, 
      LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}, 
      PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(NF\)]\)=1"}]
```

Comment: When debugging code, first check whether individual components are producing the desired results.  So, remove all those semicolons to examine the result for`u101`, etc.  There are too many curly brackets!  Starting with `n1`, use `Flatten` to remove extra pairs of brackets.  You have many other syntax errors as well, but this is a start.

Comment: Thank you so much @bbgodfrey for your reply. I was trying that way only but was not able to get my output, might be missing something. That's why I put this here.

Answer (score 3):

You have several `Evaluate`'s that aren't necessary, and pairs of braces that should be removed.

This fixup of your code produces a result:

```
k = 1.5;
H = 2;
ρ = 1;
μ = 1;
△ = (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]*H;
α = 2;
n = α^2 + △^2;
q = △*Sqrt[μ/ρ];
p = Sqrt[q^2 + α^2];
ϵ = 0.1;
c = 0;
z = 0.5*π;
t = 1;
σ = 0.01;
n1 = First@
   NDSolve[{((y + k)^2*u100''[y]) + ((y + k)*u100'[y]) - u100[y] + 
       k*(y + k)*H^2 == 
      0, ((y + k)^2*u200''[y]) + ((y + k)*u200'[y]) - u200[y] + 
       k*(y + k)*μ*H^2 == 0,
     ((y + k)^2*f1''[y]) + ((y + k)*
         f1'[y]) - ((α*(y + k))^2 + 1)*f1[y] == 0,
     ((y + k)^2*f2''[y]) + ((y + k)*
         f2'[y]) - ((α*(y + k))^2 + 1)*f2[y] == 0,
     ((y + k)^2*f3''[y]) + ((y + k)*
         f3'[y]) - ((α*(y + k))^2 + 1)*f3[y] == 0,
     ((y + k)^2*f4''[y]) + ((y + k)*
         f4'[y]) - ((α*(y + k))^2 + 1)*f4[y] == 
      0, ((y + k)^2*u110''[y]) + ((y + k)*
         u110'[y]) - ((△*(y + k))^2 + 1)*u110[y] + 
       k*(y + k)*H^2 == 
      0, ((y + k)^2*u210''[y]) + ((y + k)*
         u210'[y]) - ((q*(y + k))^2 + 1)*u210[y] + 
       k*μ*(y + k)*H^2 == 
      0, ((y + k)^2*f5''[y]) + ((y + k)*f5'[y]) - ((n*(y + k))^2 + 1)*
        f5[y] == 0,
     ((y + k)^2*f6''[y]) + ((y + k)*f6'[y]) - ((n*(y + k))^2 + 1)*
        f6[y] == 0,
     ((y + k)^2*f7''[y]) + ((y + k)*f7'[y]) - ((p*(y + k))^2 + 1)*
        f7[y] == 0,
     ((y + k)^2*f8''[y]) + ((y + k)*f8'[y]) - ((p*(y + k))^2 + 1)*
        f8[y] == 0,
     u100[-1] == 0,
     u200[1] == 0,
     u100[0] == u200[0],
     μ*u100'[0] == u200'[0],
     f1[-1] == -Cos[c]*u100'[-1],
     f2[-1] == -Sin[c]*u100'[-1],
     f3[1] == -u200'[1],
     f4[1] == 0,
     f1[0] == f3[0],
     f2[0] == f4[0],
     μ*f1'[0] == f3'[0],
     μ*f2'[0] == f4'[0],
     u110[-1] == 0,
     u210[1] == 0,
     u110[0] == u210[0],
     μ*u110[0] == u210[0],
     f5[-1] == -Cos[c]*u110'[-1],
     f6[-1] == -Sin[c]*u110'[-1],
     f7[1] == -u210'[1],
     f8[1] == 0,
     f5[0] == f7[0],
     f6[0] == f8[0],
     μ*f5'[0] == f7'[0],
     μ*f6'[0] == f8'[0]}, {u100, u200, u110, u210, f1, f2, f3, f4,
      f5, f6, f7, f8}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", 
      "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", 
        "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}}];
u101 = (f1[y]*Sin[α*z] + f2[y]*Cos[α*z]) /. n1;
u201 = (f3[y]*Sin[α*z] + f4[y]*Cos[α*z]) /. n1;
u111 = (f5[y]*Sin[α*z] + f6[y]*Cos[α*z]) /. n1;
u211 = (f7[y]*Sin[α*z] + f8[y]*Cos[α*z]) /. n1;
u10 = (u100[y] + ϵ*u101) /. n1;
u11 = (u110[y] + ϵ*u111) /. n1;
u20 = (u200[y] + ϵ*u201) /. n1;
u21 = (u210[y] + ϵ*u211) /. n1;
p1 = Plot[
  Piecewise[{{Re[(u10 + (σ*(E^(I*t))*u11)) /. n1], -1 <= y <= 
      0}, {Re[(u20 + (σ*(E^(I*t))*u21)) /. n1], 
     0 <= y <= 1}}], {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  AxesLabel -> {y, U}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Thick}, ImageSize -> 260, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(NF\)]\)=1"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @flinty, for the help. I also have one more issue in one another code regarding this shooting technique only, but their number of differential equations is more. If you don't mind can you please help me with that as well?

Comment: @KomalGoyal You can upvote the answer by the upper triangle ▲ on the left of the answer, as I have done.